# aws-RunPatchBaseline reboot option

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ssm

I am planning to use SSM to patch the Linux server. we have 2 separate schedules 1. kernel patching, 2 non-kernal patchings. we don't normally reboot machines while doing non-kernal patching but aws SSM  runpatchbaseline is rebooting machine irrespective of whatever patching I am doing. is there a way I can control this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible, as the AWS-RunPatchBaseline document doesn't provide options to control the reboot behavior.

Docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/patch-manager-about-aws-runpatchbaseline.html

> Whenever an update is installed on an instance, the instance is rebooted to ensure the update is both installed and active.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, i would love to have this param too. It look like aws enforce the use of Auto Scaling Group for your instances. This task can update instance one by one into the same scaling group. This way your not impacted by the reboot.

EDIT:
It look like they did add a option for it : 
`
RebootOption String (Optional) Reboot behavior after a patch Install operation. If you choose NoReboot and patches are installed, the instance is marked as non-compliant until a subsequent reboot and scan.

Value can be : RebootIfNeeded or NoReboot
`

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible with the parameter [`RebootOption`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/patch-manager-aws-runpatchbaseline.html#patch-manager-aws-runpatchbaseline-parameters-norebootoption).

```
Usage: Optional.
Options: RebootIfNeeded | NoReboot
Default: RebootIfNeeded
```

Example:

```bash
aws ssm send-command \
    --document-name 'AWS-RunPatchBaseline' \
    --targets Key=InstanceIds,Values='i-00000000000000000' \
    --parameters 'Operation=Install,RebootOption=RebootIfNeeded'
```